# Autocomplete pycharm doesn't work when using patch module in unittest

Tags: python, autocomplete, mocking, pycharm

Following code works fine, it's a very simple test to mock away the print function. The problem is when I call mocked_print and want autocomplete *mocked_print* with the method *assert_called_once_with* doesn't show up among suggestions in the editor.

[Here's an image of the suggestions I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gOqo.png)

Environment:

- Windows 10
- PyCharm community Edition 2019.2.2
- python 3.7.4.exe

```
import unittest
from unittest import mock

def print_something():
    print('Hello')

class TestFoo(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_print(self):
        with mock.patch('builtins.print') as mocked_print:
            print_something()
            mocked_print.assert_called_once_with("Hello")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could navigate to `mock.patch` definition and see that it is typed as `_patch` object that has no `assert_called_once_with`.

PyCharm uses stubs from [typeshed](https://github.com/python/typeshed) for `unittest` so it seems that corresponding stub should be revised.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I'm a bit new to the Python/Pycharm world, I still haven't been able to figure this one out - does this mean that Pycharm is looking at the wrong definition of patch?